# assign variables in apply()-d function using <<-

Tags: r

In R, I want to call *apply* on a huge data.frame, and write values back into specific positions of other dataframes.

However, using '<<-' only works when I call the apply function from the global environment. As I understand, '<<-' searches the parent.env() for the variable. Why is the parent environment of the function called in bar() not bar's environment?
Thanks!

```
do_write_foo1 <- function(x) {
    cat("parent environment of function called in bar():  ")
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    foo1[x['a']] <<- 100+x['a']
}
do_write_foo2 <- function(x) {
    foo2[x['a']] <<- 100+x['a']
}

bar <- function() {
    cat("bar environment:  ")
    print(environment())
    foo1 <- 1:10
    apply(data.frame(a=1:10),1,do_write_foo1)
    foo1
}

# this does not work:    
bar()
# bar environment:  <environment: 0x3bb6278>
# parent environment of function called in bar():  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# Error in foo1[x["a"]] <<- 100 + x["a"] : object 'foo1' not found


# this works:
foo2<-1:10
apply(data.frame(a=1:10),1,do_write_foo2)
foo2
#  [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Comment: Note that in the first run, bar() doesn't find foo. Try to run it after rm(foo). That means it's not searching inside the function. Why ?

Comment: Thanks for noting, it was a mistake I made and changed it to have two different variable names. 

The reason it does not find the variable is that the parent.env() of the bar-called function is not bar's environment. But also I do not know why it is like that.

Comment: This is very much against the spirit of R programming.  It's usually best to avoid function with non-local side effects.

Comment: Yes, it's against the functional spirit of R. However, I use this type of assignment to read a huge file into several data frames. If I could not pre-define these dataframes and write to them directly, I'd use another programming language for speed and memory reasons. So for me ther pros here are greater than the cons of possible side effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am inside a package namespace, I have to use a solution different to Etiennebr's. And I think it is rather elegant: Assigning the environment of bar to do_write_foo1.

```
do_write_foo1 <- function(x) {
    cat("parent environment of function called in bar():  ")
    print(parent.env(environment()))
    foo1[x['a']] <<- 100+x['a']
}

bar <- function() {
    cat("bar environment:  ")
    print(environment())
    foo1 <- 1:10
     environment(do_write_foo1) <- environment()
    apply(data.frame(a=1:10),1,do_write_foo1)
    foo1
}

# now it works:    
bar()
```

Comment: Given your constaints, it is a nice solution. However, I would think the environments are like matryoshka dolls going one in the other as they are called. It seems it is not the case with <<-. It goes beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems R is not searching inside the function (I don't understand why), so you need to assign the value to the global.env foo.

```
bar <- function() {
    foo <<-1:10
    apply(data.frame(a=1:10),1,do_write_foo)
    foo
}
bar()
# [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves that question. For my problem at hand, unfortunately, it only leads to a next problem:

Error in .local(filename, type, ...) : 
  cannot change value of locked binding for 'spectrumTitles'

(It is the variable spectrumTitles I want to assign to).
I am developing a package, and inside a package it might not be possible to use <<-.

Comment: Maybe you could look at using something like 

  assign("foo", foo, loadNamespace("YourPackage"))